# if I have a set of data (A1:D8) how do I filter a column to show if a value contains a number VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, filtering, excel-2010

A  B

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BRYCE | N6285 |  | M |
| BRIANNA | N5745 | 15 | F |
| MAX | N6652 |  | M |
| FAN | N4651 | 8 | F |
| DANNIE | N6681 |  | F |
| MILLIE | N6561 |  | F |
| SUNNY | N5651 | 11 | M |
| RON | N6354 | 12 | M |

```
With Selection
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="N6", 
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="", 
    End With
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="19"
```

want to filter column B with values that contain "N6" and column C that are blank to replace the blanks in column C with the value of "19"

when I run it, it doesn't fill in the blanks as it only filters the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to reply because I can interpret this question two ways: 1) how to filter data using VBA; or 2) how to fill empty cells if the cell to their left contains "N6". Your question mentions filtering, but it sounds like your goal is actually #2. If that's not the case, and your goal really is setting up the filtering, please clarify that in your post, and accept my apologies for misinterpreting!

And when you say cells that "contain N6", I assume you mean **begin with** N6, as in your data.

Instead of filtering, assuming that's not your real goal :), I would just look down the columns and replace as needed. I would also specify the range instead of using Select.

```
Sub N6ReplaceBlanks()
    Dim rngRow As Range, rngData As Range
    
    '  Specify the range instead of using Select
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D8")
    
    ' Look at every row in the data
    For Each rngRow In rngData.Rows
        ' Test whether columns B and C in the row match our criteria
        If Left(rngRow.Cells(1, 2), 2) = "N6" And rngRow.Cells(1, 3) = "" Then
            rngRow.Cells(1, 3) = 19
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub FilterAndReplace()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the range to filter
    Set filterRange = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastRow)
    
    ' Filter column B to show only values starting with "N6"
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="N6*"
    
    ' Replace blank values in column C with 19
    filterRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 19
End Sub
```